# Kafka connect MongoDB Kafka connector using JSONConverter not working

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to configure the Kafka connector to use mongoDB as the source and send the records into Kakfa topics.
I've successfully done so, but I'm trying to do it with the JSONConverter in order to also save the schema with the payload.

My problem is that the connector is saving the data as follows:

```
{ "schema": { "type": "string" } , "payload": "{....}" }
```

In other words, it's automatically assuming the actual JSON is a string and it's saving the schema as String.

This is how I'm setting up the connector:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8083/connectors -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
 "name": "newtopic",
 "config": { 
"tasks.max":1,
 "connector.class":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector", 
 "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter", 
 "key.converter.schemas.enabled": "true",
 "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter", 
 "value.converter.schemas.enabled": "true",
 "connection.uri":"[MONGOURL]", 
 "database":"dbname", 
 "collection":"collname", 
 "pipeline":"[]", 
 "topic.prefix": "", 
 "publish.full.document.only": "true" 
 }}'
```

Am I missing something for the configuration? Is it simply not able to guess the schema of the document stored in MongoDB, so it goes with String?

Comment: Note: Kafka Connect is not specific to Confluent. There's no such thing as Confluent Kafka

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue with one of the given answers?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing to guess. Mongo is schemaless, last I checked, so the schema is a string or bytes. I would suggest using AvroConverter or setting schema enabled to false

You may also want to try using Debezium to see if you get different results

Comment: Thanks for the response, a couple of comments: 1- I know mongo is schemaless, I was under the impression the connector would infer the schema from the document being submitted. 2- Debezium is not an option as the confluent connector has some features I need. 3- I need schema and Avro uses schema registry which is not accessible for the pyspark API.

Comment: 1- what is there to infer? I've never used Mongo with a schema before... 2 - Confluent did not develop the Mongo source connector. Mongo the company did... 3 - Avro/schema registry indeed is available from pyspark, I've done it before

Answer (score 0):

The latest [version 1.3](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongo-db-connector-for-apache-kafka-1-3-available-now) of the MongoDB connector should solve this issue.
It even provides an option for inferring the source schema.